# Accessing ICS computer from the LAN

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I connected Computer C to Computer A through Windows ICS (Internet Connection Sharing). Win7 (A) assigns an IP address to C. As expected, computer C now has access to the internet.

My problem is this, I am able to ping computer C from computer A. But I want to be able to access it from Computer B (which gives a ping timeout to C)

What I understand is that C is in a different network because of the 137. So, how can I put the new computer into the same network? I tried http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230148 but they mention a registry that does not seem to exist in Win7 (Hkey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ICSharing\Settings\General). Am I on the right path here or not?

Or.. Should I be using a Connection Bridge?

```
 Comp A(192.168.0.129) -----ICS---------- Comp C(192.168.137.203)
   |
   |
 Router/DHCP Server ----- Internet
   |
   |
 Comp B(192.168.0.126)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either I have misunderstood your setup or that is not the intended usage of ICS. To my knowledge ICS does NAT which grants the computers 'behind' the ICS gateway a one way connection to the other network (usually the internet) but is not intended to forward requests from the internet to computers on the 'inside'.

If Comp B and Comp C are actually not located at the same 'site' but seperated by the internet, you might rather be looking into seting up a VPN connection to get all interested computers into the same virtual network. One way to do so would be to setup [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html) on Comp A and having Comp C and Comp B connect to Comp A.

Comment: Computers A and B are in the same site, joined by a simple wifi router. Computer C is hooked to computer A through the ethernet port. I wish to access computer C from within my local LAN. Not from the internet.

Comment: Or.. Should I be using a Connection Bridge?

Comment: So Computers A and B are connected using wifi to your wifi router? And C is connected to the same wifi router but through one of its ethernet ports? If that is the case, look for options in your router to bridge the wifi and lan (the wifi routers Ive dealt with so far do that by default actually). Maybe you specified different IP ranges for the two connections, try changing that to the same range, that might do the trick.